# How to get multiple git-graphs at a time?

Tags: git, shell, ubuntu

i wrote a shell script for displaying three git graphs, but when i run it i could get only one or two outputs at a time. By observing the terminal i found that a graph is repeating twice. I couldn't understand the reason why this is happening.Please help me to get all three graphs at a time.
Here is the shell script code I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir q2
cd q2
git init
mkdir 12140900-member-1
cd 12140900-member-1
echo "iitbhilai" > hello-world
git add .
git commit -m "file of member-1"
cd ..
git graph
mkdir 12140210-member-2
cd 12140210-member-2
echo "iitbhilai" > hello-world
git add .
git commit -m "file of member-2"
cd ..
git graph
mkdir 12140880-member-3
cd 12140880-member-3
echo "iitbhilai" > hello-world
git add .
git commit -m "file of member-3"
cd ..
git graph
```

Here is the pic of the output in terminal:

[image: output in terminal]

i tried to get three git-graphs at a time with this code, but i was only getting two at a time.

Comment: I count "... saved in .../.gitGraph" _three_ times. I also count 3 commits. How do you come up with 2?

Comment: @knittl I too couldn't understand that, the output in terminal shws that three graphs are saved but two of them have same id, so only two graphs are popping up. I don't know how to resolve this.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know what the alias `git graph` does or is supposed to do. All your commits have unique and distinct ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem while making the git graph, I solved it using `sleep <TIME IN SECONDS>` (suggestion take sleep time >0.5s).

**Not sure**, but I think that `git` shell commands are running so fast as compared to `git graph`, that they make it override the graph. (Again this is just my theory, but the solution works)

I hope this helps ✌️